# How can i parse HttpResponse in .Net 6.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

I am sending request to an api with HttpClient. The response from the request works without any problem, but I cannot parse the key values I want in the response. According to the research I have done, I tried such a code, but the incoming data returns empty in this way. How can I get the values I want from the incoming data?

```
using LoggerApi.Methods;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;

namespace LoggerApi.Methods
{
    public class ApiMethods
    {
    
        public async static Task<object> GetClientInformations(string authenticationCode, string username = "username")
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var userInformationEndpoint = new Uri("https://myurl.com/url");
            var userInformationPayload = new UserInformationPayload()
            {
                Login = username
            };
            var serializePayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userInformationPayload);
            var payload = new StringContent(serializePayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var res = await client.PostAsync(userInformationEndpoint, payload).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var responseResultJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(res);
            return responseResultJson;


        }
    }

}
```

this code output is empty looks like this

```
{
  "HasError": [],
  "AlertType": [],
  "AlertMessage": [],
  "ModelErrors": [],
  "Data": [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [
          [
            []
          ],
          [
            []
          ],
          [
            []
          ],
          [
            []
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

But when I return `var res` directly instead of `var responseResultJson` from the function, the result is like this. What I want to do here is to access values such as Login, FirstName, LastName, Id from the incoming data. How can I do that?

```
{"HasError":false,"AlertType":"success","AlertMessage":"Operation has completed successfully","ModelErrors":[],"Data":{"Count":1,"Objects":[{"Id":291031530,"CurrencyId":"TRY","FirstName":"Scott","LastName":"Marshall","MiddleName":"William","Login":"scotty3"}]}}
```

Comment: Don't deserialize to `object`, make a proper class that maps to the json. And, your code would not compile so it can be difficult to reason about it knowing what you have shown is not what is actually executing.

Comment: I agree with @Crowcoder. [This JSON to C# converter](https://json2csharp.com/) can sometimes be helpful. Separately, and in my opinion, you use `var` too much.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible solutions. Once of them is the following.

```cs
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        // We need this to create a new ToDo 
        record TodoDto(int UserId, string Title, string Body);
        // That's what's stored in the backend service and returned by the API
        record TodoModel(int Id, int UserId, string Title, string Body);

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // HTTP Client
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            // required as Properties are PascalCase in C# but JSON properties here are camelCase (that's usually the case) 
            var serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions {
                PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
            };
            // create new todo
            var newTodo = new TodoDto(1, "My new todo", "I need to...");
            // Add todo in the backend
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<TodoDto>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", newTodo, serializerOptions);
            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
                // if we have a succesful request we can deserialize the response
                var newTodoModel = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<TodoModel>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), serializerOptions);
                Console.WriteLine(newTodoModel);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Request failed with status code {(int)response.StatusCode} ({response.StatusCode})");
            }
        }
}
```

Some remarks:

- I am using [JsonPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/) for some sample API endpoints to provide a working example here
- Deserializing the API response to JSON could fail e.g. when the API returns something unexpected, so you should check for that especially if you don't control the API that you're calling.
- For this to work you need to include the `System.Net.Http.Json` namespace at it contains the `PostAsJsonAsync()` extension method (see [HttpClienJsonExtensions Class - Microsoft Learn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions?view=net-6.0) for more nice and convenient extension methods).
- There is no need for Newtonsoft JSON parser, as you can now use the built-in JSON Parser in the `System.Text.Json` namespace.
- I prefer working with `Streams` as you can then use `async` all the way throughout your code which is a best practice (see [Async best practices - Async All the Way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#async-all-the-way))
- By default a case-sensitive matching between your C# class and the JSON will be attempted. JSON usually uses camelCase and this API does so as well. Therefore we need to tell the (de-)serializer to use camelCase as well using [`JsonSerializerOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=net-6.0).